# How to ouput value of matching case in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var hashtags = [ '#hr', '#acc', '#sales', '#hr' ];
```

I understand that to look for a specified matching value I'd have to use this

```
if (hashtags.indexOf("#hr") > -1)
    // output value
```

But how do I output ALL the matching values that match the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#filter` and equality comparison to get all the occurrences of your word in the given array.

```js
var hashtags = [ '#hr', '#acc', '#sales', '#hr' ];
var result = hashtags.filter( word => word === '#hr');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check inside the condition. Also instead of `indefOf` you can use [**Array#includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function.

```js
const hashtags = [ '#hr', '#acc', '#sales', '#hr' ];

const filteredHashtags = hashtags.filter(item => item.includes('#hr'));

console.log(filteredHashtags);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   string [] arr = {"One","Two","Three"};
   var target = "One";
   var results = Array.FindAll(arr, s => s.Equals(target));
```

Comment: Javascript is not Java !